# Terraform concatenate sublists

Tags: terraform

I would like to get combined list from sublists of an object list.

I have a list object like:

```
users: [
  {
    name: "a"
    cars: [
      "z1",
      "z2"
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "b"
    cars: [
      "x1",
      "x2"
    ]
  }
]
```

and result should be:

```
cars = ["z1", "z2", "x1", "x2"]
```

The main reason is that I need to execute resource on each element:

```
resource "some_resource" "some_resource_name" {
  for_each = var.cars
  car_name = each.value
}
```

If there is a way to do it directly in resource, perfect. Or if I need to pre-build the list in locals that also is not a problem.
How do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be achieved easily with combining a [`splat`](https://www.terraform.io/language/expressions/splat) expression with [`flatten`](https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/flatten) function:

```
locals {
  cars = flatten([
    var.users[*].cars
  ])
}
```

Other solution would be to use a [`for`](https://www.terraform.io/language/expressions/for) expression:

```
locals {
  cars = flatten([
    for user in var.users: user.cars
  ])
}
```

The result for `cars` in both cases will be:

```
cars = [
  "z1",
  "z2",
  "x1",
  "x2",
]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
local {
  cars = flatten([
    for user, cars in var.users : [
      for car in cars: {
        user = user
        car  = car
      }
    ]
  ])
}
```

will not produce the perfect result but is a working solution
result will be:

```
[
  {
    user = "a",
    car = "z1"
  },
  {
    user = "a",
    car = "z2"
  },
  {
    user = "b",
    car = "x1"
  },
  {
    user = "b",
    car = "x2"
  }
]
```